# Pageblocksection data display

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable

I have a custom object - `Obj__c`. In a vf page when I return those object records under a pageblock section with column="2" in order by sequence field value, they showup as 1st , 3rd , 5th record under column 1. 2nd , 4th , 6th record under column 2.

I need to show them as 1st , 2nd , 3rd under column 1 and 4th , 5th , 6th under column 2.

Please let me know how can I achieve that?

Page code:

```
 <apex:repeat value="{!FieldSObjs}" var="s"> //FieldSObjs this is the metadata //object records referred to.
                 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!s.dispUpdate == 'Update Only' || s.dispUpdate == 'Display and Update'}">
                     <apex:outputText >{!s.Label}</apex:outputText>
                     <apex:panelGroup >
                         <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!s.updFlag}" onchange="updUpdateSec();void(0);"/>
                         <apex:inputText disabled="{!!s.updFlag}" value="{!s.newvalue}" maxlength="{!s.len}" rendered="{!s.type == 'STRING' || s.type == 'TEXTAREA'}"/>
                         <apex:input disabled="{!!s.updFlag}" type="number" value="{!s.newNumValue}" rendered="{!s.type == 'INTEGER' || s.type == 'CURRENCY' || s.type == 'DECIMAL' || s.type == 'PERCENT' || s.type == 'DOUBLE'}"/>
                         <apex:input disabled="{!!s.updFlag}" type="date" value="{!s.newValueDate}" rendered="{!s.type == 'DATE'}"/>
                         <apex:input disabled="{!!s.updFlag}" type="datetime-local" value="{!s.newValueDateTime}" rendered="{!s.type == 'DATETIME'}"/>
                         <apex:input disabled="{!!s.updFlag}" type="time" value="{!s.newValueTime}" rendered="{!s.type == 'TIME'}"/>    
                         <apex:inputCheckbox disabled="{!!s.updFlag}" value="{!s.newvalueBoolean}" rendered="{!s.type == 'BOOLEAN'}"/> 
                         <apex:selectList disabled="{!!s.updFlag}" rendered="{!s.type == 'PICKLIST' && s.depPicklist = false}" size="1" value="{!s.newvalue}" >
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!s.plist}"/>
                            <apex:actionSupport action="{!s.invokeDepPicklistRefresh}" event="onchange" reRender="pb3">
                            </apex:actionSupport>
                         </apex:selectList>   
                         <apex:selectList disabled="{!!s.updFlag}" rendered="{!s.type == 'PICKLIST' && s.depPicklist = true}" size="1" value="{!s.newvalue}" >
                            <apex:selectOptions rendered="{!s.depPicklist = true}" value="{!s.depList}"/>
                         </apex:selectList>
                         <!--apex:commandButton action="{!s.getDepValues}" rendered="{!s.depPicklist = true}" value="Refresh"/-->
                     </apex:panelGroup>
                 </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
             </apex:repeat>
```

Class Code:

```
 oConfigRecordFieldList = [SELECT  Id , Default_Value_abv__c , Display_Update_abv__c , Field_API_abv__c , MUP_Config_abv__c , Name , Search_Flag_abv__c  
                                    FROM Mass_Update_Process_Field_abv__c where MUP_Config_abv__c  = :ConfigRecordId order by order_abv__c];

                objDesc =  gd.get(oConfigRecord.Object_API_Name_abv__c).getDescribe();  
                objFieldMap = objDesc.fields.getMap();   
                objChilds = objDesc.getChildRelationships();         

                FieldSObjs = new List<cField>();
               // displayFieldSObjs = new List<cField>();
               FieldSObjsMap = new Map<String,cField>();
               depFieldMap = new Map<String,List<String>>();

                for(Mass_Update_Process_Field_abv__c f: oConfigRecordFieldList)
                {
                    sRecordTypeSObjType = '';
                    if(objFieldMap.get(f.Field_API_abv__c) != null)
                    {                   
                        cField cf = new cField(objFieldMap.get(f.Field_API_abv__c).getDescribe(),f.Name, f.Field_API_abv__c,f.Search_Flag_abv__c, f.Display_Update_abv__c,f.Id,this);
                        FieldSObjs.add(cf);
                        FieldSObjsMap.put(cf.apiname, cf);
                    }
```

Comment: Please add the VF code from your page & the Apex code from your controller / extension to your post, otherwise all we will be able to do is guess.

Answer (score 2):

okie!!!

so for this you need to take 3 `<apex:pageBlockSection>` and than for first `<apex:pageBlockSection>` you need to give `columns="2"` and for rest 2 `<apex:pageBlockSection>` you need to give `columns="1"` and than in second `<apex:pageBlockSection>` include 1st , 2nd , 3rd fields and in third `<apex:pageBlockSection>` include 4th , 5th , 6th  .. see example below :

```
<apex:page standardController="contact">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" showHeader="true" title="Test">
         <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!contact.FirstName}"  /> <!-- 1st -->
                <apex:inputField value="{!contact.LastName}"  /><!-- 2nd -->
                <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Email}"  /><!-- 3rd -->

        </apex:pageBlockSection>      
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Title}"  /> <!-- 4th -->
                <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Birthdate}"  /><!-- 5th  -->
                <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Phone }"  /><!-- 6th -->

        </apex:pageBlockSection>      
        </apex:pageBlockSection>      
        </apex:pageBlock >
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This works great. Nice workaround.

Comment: But I am not having these data directly. I have a metadata object to fetch data from there. I can't directly hardcode Field Names in my case.

Comment: okie !!! so if this is prob can u please post your code !! so that we can help you out

Comment: I have added codes to my question. Please have a look